# Why qt objects lose their values?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm pretty new to qt and c++.I have a simple phone book project which can add contact to a vector object.This vector object is a private member of phonebook class.My problem is that when i add the contact(in a seperate class)and pass it's vector object to phonebook class, and then i want to write contact's information in a file,vector object datas are gone.Why does this happen?
This is the connection between signal and slot :

```
connect(pbn3, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &phonebook::addSLOT);
```

and this is add contact slot:

```
void phonebook::addSLOT()
{
    acform = new AddContact();
    acform->receiveVec(vec);
    acform->show();
}
```

(acform is a pointer of AddContact class which is a private member of phonebook class)
and this is add function in AddContact class:

```
void AddContact::sendData()
{
    contact c;
    c.name = led->text().toStdString();
    c.phone_number = ted->toPlainText().toStdString();
    vec.push_back(c);
    phonebook d;
    d.recieveData(vec);
    this->close();
}
```

and in this function i receive the vector object :

```
void phonebook::recieveData(vector<contact> _vec)
{
    vec.clear();
    vec = _vec;
}
```

But after using this function,object datas are gone.
Every help is appreciated :)

Comment: you create `phonebook d;` on stack, this will be destroyed at end of `SendData()` - where do you store it in the private part? do you save to disk?

Comment: you say `AddContact` is member of `phonebook`. Then `sendData` should call `receiveData` on the "parent" phonebook, and not on a new phonebook!

Comment: @KYL3R yes, in receiveData function which is a member of phonebook function,i assign the main vector to the new vector.(i added it in my post)

Comment: @KYL3R no,AddContact is a seperate class,it's not a member of phonebook.

Comment: You posted only parts of the program, so it's hard to examine what's is going wrong. What I see, is that every time You call 'addSLOT' you cerate new object on stash and overite the 'acform' pointer. What do You do in between the calls? What happens with previously allocated 'acform' objects? When and where they are destroyed?

Comment: ***Why qt objects lose thier value?*** This is not a Qt only thing. It's very basic `c++`. You need to learn about scope and storage duration. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/scope-visual-cpp?view=vs-2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/scope-visual-cpp?view=vs-2019) and [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)

Comment: @b00rt00s when i call the receiveVec function by acform pointer,it passes the phonebook vector object to AddContact class and i assign it to vector object of AddContact class,then i add the contact and phonebook vector object is updated as i've showed in the code in my post.

Comment: @drescherjm Thank you!The article about storage duration was helpful.

Comment: @Fargol_sh I've seen 'recieveData' method and it has nothing to do with managing of a lifetime of 'AddContact' objects that are assigned to the 'acform' pointer.